# unable to configure through carbon.xml

Tags: configuration, wso2, config

I am trying to configure wso2 by modifing its configuration file named "carbon.xml", but no matter what change I do to "carbon.xml", even adding a single "white space" or modifying a comment it's enough for the wso2 server to reset carbon.xml file to it´s original "out of the box" state.
I tryied to protect the file carbon.xml by dropping write permissions, but in this case wso2 server refuses to start, it aborts execution and displays an error complaining that it was not able to "write new configuration" !!!
Does any one know how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer, In wso2 version 5.9 there is a new centralized configuration file, named "deployment.toml". Configurations must be done in this file and then wso2 propagates changes to the respective configurations files, like carbon.xml or catalina-server.xml, for example.
If you delete "deployment.toml" wso2 will fallback to previos behavior.

Answer (score 0):

With the new 4.5.0 carbon-kernel release, all WSO2 products such as APIM 3.0.0, IS 5.9.0 introduced a new config model. According to the new config model, there is a centralized configuration file (deployment.toml) where users add the configurations, then those configurations will be added to the respective .xml files.

This new config model was introduced in order to simplify the configuration (previously there were a lot of configuration files) and to increase the user experience. Please follow this documentation to refer further information on this new config model

Related documents:

https://wso2.com/blogs/thesource/2019/10/simplifying-configuration-with-WSO2-identity-server

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/next/references/new-configuration-model/

If you have a deployment.toml file, the changes directly made into the xml files will be overiden during the server startup. Deleting the deployment.toml file will use the old config model. But it is not a recommended approach.